# Navigate to a Page of another Class Library

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need to create several versions of a core project. Few things can change between core project and its extensions, some functionalities and, above all, design (Fonts, colors, etc). For that, I've created a `Class Library`. I made a question about that few days ago and I guessed creating the `Class Library` was the proper way to do it. Here you have a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439699/android-studio-app-module-equivalent-for-visual-studio-2015) to the post.

Now that I have all the project in the library, I'm creating those extensions and I would like to Navigate to Pages of the `Class Library` but from the extensions and I get this exception:

> **Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in MyProject.exe**
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The class library contains `UserControls` and `Pages` but I'm not sure if this is the best way around. So any suggestion or tutorial will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: No don't put your views (Pages) in the class library leave them in your Startup project. UserControls should be ok though

Comment: The idea of having the views in the class library was to reuse code... so, isn't there a way to have templates of the pages in a Global project and then attach them in the extensions? That would be exactly what I need

Comment: You need the views in startup as you need to use `Frame` to navigate successfully (forward, back, history). Theres nothing stopping you creating all the layouts in `UserControls` in your class library then adding them to the views

Comment: Puttings Pages into class libraries is a fine and convenient way to organize parts of your application. Also, it should work just fine. Did you use the right class library template: *Class Library (Windows Universal)* (it should ask you for the target windows version on creation)? Did you add the library as a reference in your main project? Maybe something else is causing your Exception and you should post more code.

Comment: @KaiBrummund yes, theoretically everything is well-created...

Comment: theoretically :) I've just built a simple sample and it worked perfectly...

Comment: I have also tried in another basic solution and it's worked! What can cause the Exception in the other project? I don't understand :S

Comment: Don't know. :) Show code. Stacktrace of the exception, etc. Otherwise, we're all just wildly guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily there is a workaround by Daniel Vaughan (http://danielvaughan.org/post/UWP-AccessViolationException-when-Navigating-to-a-Page-in-Another-Assembly.aspx):

- create a Dummy.xaml in the startup project

Comment: This only work for me in Debug build. In Release build, same problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

halllo's answer only works for me in Debug build. When I build/deploy in Release build, the problem is still there. Instead, I just remove the Navigation code and assign the content directly. So far my app works well (since I don't need Navigation, it's a single WebView app) but I do not know if there will be any problem.

```
// rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
// Remove the above default line
// MainPage is a C# class that inherits a Page in my library
rootFrame.Content = new MainPage();
```