# UWP app - navigate to Page in class library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I've seen some similar to mine questions asked (e.g. [Navigate to a Page of another Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609360/navigate-to-a-page-of-another-class-library)) but I couldn't find a solution for my problem there. So:

I have a UWP VB app. To facilitate code reuse, I decided to move some commonly used components in a class library, which I of course referenced in my main project. One of these components is a login page (LoginPage.xaml and LoginPage.xaml.vb)

In my app's App.xaml.vb, using the standard VS2015 template code, in the OnLaunched event handler, I wrote:

```
    If rootFrame.Content Is Nothing Then
            rootFrame.Navigate(GetType(MyLibrary.LoginPage), e.Arguments)
    End If
```

My app fails at this point, with a NullReferenceException (this vbCrLf concatenation looks silly!):

> Exception: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
>       Handled: False
>       Message: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." & vbCrLf & "   at MyLibrary.MyLibrary_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()" & vbCrLf & "   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)" & vbCrLf & "   at My.Test_UWP.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)"

I've seen some suggestions on similar issues to enabled the `Generate library layout` build option, but I see no such option on my environment.

On a side note, initially my plan was to navigate to this page by first providing some configuration data and subscribing to an event:

```
Dim l As New MyLibrary.LoginPage(Me.appSettings)
AddHandler l.DidLogin, AddressOf AfterLogin
rootFrame.Navigate(l.GetType)
```

This failed too with the same NullReferenceException. Stepping through this code provided - maybe - more info. The code that fails is in XmlTypeInfo.g.vb:

```
Public Overrides Function ActivateInstance() As Global.System.Object
Return Activator.Invoke()
End Function
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As the the attempt to instantiate the MyLibrary.LoginPage class with parameters, this was wrong; the proper was is to pass the params you want  like `rootFrame.Navigate(GetType(MyLibrary.LoginPage), params)` and read them in the target page's `OnNavigatedTo` handler.

Comment: Spyros P. - I'm getting the impression that you're right about passing the parameters, but this is a really sucky design.  Flies in the face of both MVVM and Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I added just a BlankPage to my class library and tried to navigate to it from the App.xaml.vb and it worked, therefore the problem was in the actual LoginPage.xaml file.

I had overloaded the class constructor to pass some parameters and obviously this was not the right way to go. Removing the overloaded constructor allowed the app to properly display the page in the class library.