# UWP Navigate throws AccessViolationException for xaml-less pages

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is it just me, or is it impossible to navigate to a page that does not have a .xaml head?

I am constructing a page entirely in code, and I want to navigate to it. I do not want a xaml page because this is a class library and also it is constructed based on data received. I know all about using .xaml to create the page with templates, binding, etc., but I want to avoid that.

When I call `Frame.Navigate(typeof(CodePage))`, I get  nice `AccessViolationException`.

My page is simple, and so is the navigation. This is the code with a clean, new project

Navigation (button click):

```cs
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(CodePage));
```

Page:

```cs
public class CodePage : Page
{
    public CodePage()
    {
        Content = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = "It works!",
        };
    }
```

I know about this issue: [Navigate to a Page of another Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609360/navigate-to-a-page-of-another-class-library) but, this is because ALL the pages are in the library, I just have 1 specific page in my library. Also, I have other pages in the "launcher" app.

Comment: Did you tried `Window.Current.Content = new CodePage();`  instead of navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation only works with pages who have xaml part as well because when the page does **InitializeComponent** in its constructor it sets up the page for Navigation routes and NavigationCache etc.