# Launch UWP app from Class Library project

Tags: c#, uwp

To improve compilation speed I'm trying to split my UWP project into 2:

1. rarely changed class library project with all views and controls,
2. another UWP project that starts everything and contains frequently changed code.

I had many problems trying to start it.

1. My `static void Main()` started the app but I got AccessViolationException so I had to add a dummy xaml page into the new UWP app project (see [Navigate to a Page of another Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609360/navigate-to-a-page-of-another-class-library))
2. Then it didn't compile (with null reference compiler exception) because it also expected to have App.xaml in the project. I added it but I had to remove my `Main` method.
3. Now I added DummyApp.xaml and inherited the App.xaml class from the class library project. The app now starts.
4. Now it gives me another error: `Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key DefaultListViewItemStyle` when navigating to `MainPage.xaml`.

Can you help me to solve it?

App.xaml contains this section:

```
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <muxc:XamlControlsResources />

                <common:Theme />
                <common:ThemeIncoming />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Common/CommonStyles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Themes/Accent.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Themes/MenuFlyout_themeresources.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Themes/TeachingTip_themeresources.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Themes/CheckBox_themeresources.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Themes/RadioButton_themeresources.xaml" />
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Themes/ScrollBar_themeresources.xaml" />-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Themes/BadgeButton_themeresources.xaml" />
                <themes:Messages />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

The `DefaultListViewItemStyle` should be in the `XamlControlsResources` but it doesn't work.

1. I tried making my DummyApp empty so that everything is inherited from the original App.xaml - didn't work,
2. I tried copying the content of App.xaml into the DummyApp.xaml - same,
3. Added and removing a call to `InitializeComponent` in the DummyApp.xaml.cs.

Comment: UWP and WinUI 2.8 do not have `DefaultListViewItemStyle`. Currently, [DefaultListViewItemStyle](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/33541da536673fa360212e94e4a6ac896b8b49fb/dev/CommonStyles/ListViewItem_themeresources.xaml#L172) can only be used in WinUI3. Is your project a UWP project?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Certainly. It's a store app.

Comment: Is `DefaultListViewItemStyle` used in xaml? If it is a UWP project, `DefaultListViewItemStyle` should not be used in code.

Comment: Yes, like this: `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem"  BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}">`

Comment: It is recommended that you do not use `DefaultListViewItemStyle` in your UWP project.  `DefaultListViewItemStyle` can only be used in WinUI3 project.